# For loop to Populate Textblocks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I want to populate 40 textblocks on an application, they all have slightly different names but in common they end in a different number.

I would like to use:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 41; i++)
{
    textblock_(i).text = array[i].ToString();
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, you can use **FindName** method.

Firstly, we get an object by FindName(Control's **x:Name**). And then cast it into your control's type. Just like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 41; i++)
{
    TextBlock tb = (this.FindName(string.Format("textblock_{0}", i)) as TextBlock);
    tb.Text = array[i].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Forms (WinForms) then:
[Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
TextBox currentTextBox = this.Controls.Find("textBox1" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as  TextBox;
currentTextBox.Text = array[i].ToString();
```

Or in WPF: [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) CrimsonX's answer

Comment: We're using WPF, sorry!

Comment: then show code that how are you adding controls to the windows

Comment: In this case you have to make a treewalk: follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type link and check CrimsonX's answer